# If three sides of an acute triangle is $3$ cm, $4$ cm, and $x$ cm. What are the possible values of $x$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**Problem:** If three sides of an acute triangle is 3 cm, 4 cm, and $x$ cm. What are the possible values of $x$?

**2 of the choices:** (A) $1<x<5$, and (B) $0<x<7$

**Solution:** According to triangle theorems, 2 sides of a triangle is greater than the 3rd side and their difference is less than the 3rd side.

From one of the choices, (ranges $0<x<7$) when $x = 6$:

1. $3 + 4 > 6$
2. $6 + 4 > 3$
3. $3 + 6 > 4$

From the above, it means $6$ is a possible value for $x$, and since choice **A** doesn't have $6$ in it, I chose **B** as the correct answer. However that isn't the case, the correct answer according to the book is A, which I don't know why. So how was it $1<x<5$? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read the question more carefully: if three sides of an **acute** triangle...

Comment: If we are told that three sides of a (*non-degenerate*) *triangle* (*without any other information about the triangle*) are $3,4,x$ then we learn from the triangle inequality that $1<x<7$.  We are however told an additional piece of information: that the triangle is *acute*.

Comment: Remember that a common example of a right triangle is a 3-4-5 right triangle.  If we were to take a 3-4-5 triangle, and instead stretch the side of length 5... the corresponding effect on the angles would be what?  What does it mean for a triangle to be [acute or obtuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_and_obtuse_triangles)?

Comment: Were there other choices than those two?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $a,b,c$ are all lengths of sides of a (*non-degenerate*) triangle, the triangle inequality implies the following conditions:

$$1.~~~~~a+b>c$$

$$2.~~~~~a+c>b$$

$$3.~~~~~b+c>a$$

Further, if $a,b,c$ are all lengths of sides of an [*acute* triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_and_obtuse_triangles), we *also* learn the following conditions:

$$4.~~~~~a^2+b^2>c^2$$

$$5.~~~~~a^2+c^2>b^2$$

$$6.~~~~~b^2+c^2>a^2$$

---

Letting $a=3,b=4,c=x$, plugging these values into inequalities 1,2,4 and 5 respectively we transform the above into the following:

$$3+4>x$$

$$3+x>4$$

$$3^2+4^2>x^2$$

$$3^2+x^2>4^2$$

Simplifying arithmetic and moving $x$ to a single side this simplifies further as:

$$7>x$$

$$x>1$$

$$25>x^2$$

$$x^2>7$$

Remembering that $x$ should be positive we can take square roots of each side of the third and fourth inequalities here and recognizing these conditions as being more restrictive than the first two inequalities we learn that

$$5>x$$

$$x>\sqrt{7}\approx 2.64$$

We have therefore the following as the maximal restrictions we can place on the value of $x$ being:

$$\sqrt{7}<x<5$$

Indeed, one can make an acute triangle with sidelengths $3,4,x$ for every value of $x$ from the set $\{x~:~\sqrt{7}<x<5\}$ and no value of $x$ outside of that set makes a valid acute triangle with sidelengths $3,4,x$ either because it would be a right triangle, an obtuse triangle, or not a triangle at all.  For example a [2-3-4 triangle](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2,3,4+triangle) is obtuse.

Answer (score 3):

Let the angles opposite the sides of lengths $x,3,4$ be $\theta,\omega, \phi$ respectively. Then by the Cosine Rule we obtain the relations: $$x^2=3^2+4^2-2\cdot3\cdot4\cos \theta,$$ $$3^2=x^2+4^2-2\cdot x\cdot4\cos \omega$$ and $$4^2=x^2+3^2-2\cdot x\cdot3\cos \phi$$ for $0<\cos \theta, \cos \omega,\cos \phi<1$.

From the first relation we have that $x^2=25-24\cos\theta$, which tells us that the extremes of $x^2$ are $25-24\times 1=1$ and $25-24\times 0=25$, so that $1<x^2<25$, or $1<x<5$.

From the second relation we deduce that $x=4\cos\omega\pm\sqrt{16\cos^2\omega-7}$, from which we learn that $x=\sqrt{-7}$ when $\cos\omega=0$ and $x=1,7$ when $\cos\omega=1$. Any way we look at these, they tell us nothing interesting.

From the third relation we have that $x=3\cos\phi\pm\sqrt{9\cos^2\phi+7}$, which tells us that $x=\sqrt7$ when $\cos\phi=0$ and $x=-1,7$ when $\cos\phi=1$. We have the possible interesting relations $\sqrt7<x<7$.

Finally, combining the inequalities $1<x<5$ and $\sqrt 7<x<7$, we have the tighter bounds $\sqrt 7<x<5$.

**PS.** I have tacitly assumed throughout that the sinusoidal functions $x(\theta),x(\omega),x(\phi)$ which we analysed are either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing (indeed they're all strictly decreasing) wherever they are defined in the intervals $0<\theta,\omega,\phi<π/2$ respectively. This can however be easily justified if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If there are only two choices given for the solution it might be easier to prove one of the solutions to be incorrect rather than the other one to be correct. x must be greater than 4 - 3 = 1, therefore the second solution is wrong and the first solution must be the correct one by default!

Comment: Given that the proof provided by other answers shows that $$\sqrt{7}<x<5$$ it would seem that both **A** and **B** answers are incorrect by that reasoning, where in fact possible values for x are within the bounds set by both answers if we accept without defining x limit.

Comment: There are 4 choices, I eliminated the others and left the 2 most possible correct answer out of the 4. I am confused with the answers above, but I'll just have to go with the if x is greater than 4, the triangle would not be an acute triangle which is indicated in the problem.

Comment: @Jayce but if $x$ is greater than $4$ it is still possible for the triangle to be acute, for example when $x=4.5$ it will still be an acute triangle.  It is highly probable that the question author got the answer incorrect by forgetting that the condition that the triangle must be acute not only places a more restrictive upper bound *but also* places a more restrictive lower bound too.